# Авто-удаление предыдущих сообщений в боте

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Как настроить автоматическую очистку предыдущих сообщений, что бы при использовании бота чат не засорялся. Пробовал команду "bot.delete_message(chatid,messageid-1)", но без успешно...

```
import sqlite3
import telebot
import requests
from telebot import types
import random
TOKEN = 'XXXX'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    adm = [1]
    if message.chat.id not in adm:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '⛔️Доступ воспрещён⛔️')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '✅Доступ разрешён✅')
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('1')
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('2')
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton('3')
        item4 = types.KeyboardButton('4')

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'HI'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == '1':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ссылка админа')
        
        elif message.text == '2':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Скоро 1')
            item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Скоро 2')
            back = types.KeyboardButton(' Назад')
            markup.add(item1, item2, back)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '2', reply_markup = markup)
```

Comment: Самый очевидный вариант - удаление по `message_id + 1`, но это не работает, если в чате много пользователей, так как во время ответа бота может появиться новое сообщение, которому присвоится этот `id`. У меня такая же задача стоит. Как удалось решить эту проблему?